# Creating animated sprites for cocos2d from a single image file without a .plist file

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am starting to learn cocos2d and I have the following issue:

I cannot seem to find a way to create sprite frames from a single png sprite file and animate them. I have found a million tutorials about using separate image files or a plist file with the png but I can't find how to do it WITHOUT one (with a regular loop that selects rectangular areas. Any help?

Comment: what type of animation you want to create as you want change the color or rotate, highlight or some thing this... i think i can help you..

Comment: To begin with I need a regular animation for walking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924385/cocos2d-move-animation-on-a-path/8937100#8937100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a sprite sheet to work in cocos2D you need both the .plist file and the .png file.

You need a CCSpriteFrameCache object which will be in sharedSpriteFrameCache and global, meaning the Sprite frame cache is not only for the method but will exist in the memory until you remove it. Then you have to make a CCBatchNode object which will contain the sprite sheet file reference.

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"EntryJump.plist"];

CCSpriteBatchNode *entrySpriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"PotkaEntry.pvr.ccz"];
```

I am using .pvr.ccz format, you may use .png file if you want.

What I am trying to say here is that it is necessary to load the .plist file on the Sprite frame cache for cocos2D where everything is defined and loaded globally, then cocos2D will use the CCSpriteBatchNode object (the sprite sheet) where the individual images of the sprite are explained in the .plist file.

Comment: What if I find some sprite images on my own and need to create a plist for them? Again, I'm talking about sprite compilation images. I've tried both texturepacker and zwoptex, still can't find how to break up frames from one sprite file.

Comment: you just need to call frame name plist automatically do that for you no need to cut it from the whole image.

Comment: @Haroon, and how do I do that? Is there a tutorial online or something? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: If you don't have a .plist file and happen to have a sprite sheet file anyway, I don't think it will work in cocos2D because it needs the .plist file for setting the frame cache. But if you are developing for Unity 3D then no property list file needed. However, what you can do is use Preview or maybe Photoshop and cut the images to a specific size and save them individually. Then generate a sprite sheet using Texture Packer or Zwoptex and it will generate a .plist file for you.